# Design pattern - Models

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

In my application there is a model - **Drug**

```
class Drug{
  String drugId;
  String name;
  String strength;
}
```

this interface takes a drugId and returns the Drug Model

```
interface IProcessor{
Drug getDrug(String drugId);
}

// easy flow
class ProcessorA extends IProcessor{
protected Drug getDrug(String drugId){
  //get Drug from source A
  return Drug
}
}
```

// From source B, I will be getting additional fields. Am not sure how i can append the new fields
to the drug Model

```
class ProcessorB extends IProcessor{
protected Drug getDrug(String drugId){
//get Drug from source B
// Add few more fields specific to B 
  return Drug
}
}
```

1) Extend the Drug model (class DrugB extends Drug) for ProcessorB and add the new fields. In this case, I might be ending up typecasting the DrugB. Is this ok?

2) Add the common fields to Drug Class and use it. This is fine, but number of fields for each type of processor could be increasing.

Is there any patterns I should be thinking of. Please advice.

Comment: First, this is wrong `class ProcessorA extends IProcessor`, a class cannot extend an interface, it must implement it. Second, why do you have to add fields with each **processor**? This doesn't seem like a proper design choice. Your model should not depend on the processors.

Comment: My bad.. that was a typo.. which i just typed in Notepad. I will correct it. For your next question - ProcessorB will call a webservice which returns a Json response, which is converted to Drug object. But this response has few fields specific to this source.